# TestCafe - assertions not working (object tested must be an array etc.)

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, assertion, testcafe

I have a very simple assertion:

```
const mappingInput = 'input[data-test="appMS_mappingSite_inputField"]';
const mappingInputValue = "*";
.expect(mappingInput.value).contains(mappingInputValue, 'input contains *', { timeout: 500 })
```

but when I run test it fails (even though that I know for a fact that input.value contains "*".

Error message is as follows:

```
AssertionError: input contains *: object tested must be an array, a
      map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but undefined given
```

Is there something wrong with my script or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `mappingInput` constant is a string. The string type has no `value` property, so the expression `mappingInput.value` will always return `undefined`.
If you are using TestCafe you can access an input value on a test page through the [Selector](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/) API. The following example might suit your needs: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#define-assertion-actual-value

Comment: Sorry for late response but was busy with work stuff. It worked just perfect. Thank you.